# Applying GROUP BY when using multiple CASE WHEN

Tags: sql-server

```
select
 e_id
,CASE WHEN w_id in ('1','2') THEN w_id ELSE 0 END as new_w_id
,CASE WHEN w_id = 1 THEN fee END as value1
,CASE WHEN w_id = 2 THEN fee END as value2
,CASE WHEN w_id not in ('1','2') THEN fee END as value3
from table1
```

The above code gives me a result like:

```
e_id | new_w_id | value1 | value2 | value3
 1   |   1      |   100  | null   | null
 1   |   2      | null   |   150  | null
 1   |   0      | null   | null   |    50
 1   |   0      | null   | null   |   150
```

but I'd like to group by e_id and get result like:

```
e_id | new_w_id | value1 | value2 | value3
 1   |   1      |   100  | null   | null
 1   |   2      | null   |   150  | null
 1   |   0      | null   | null   |   200
```

I've tried

```
group by e_id
```

and

```
group by e_id, CASE WHEN w_id in ('1','2') THEN w_id ELSE 0 END
```

but neither of these are grouping my data as I'd like. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Would you possibly be able to provide more info pertaining to the type of grouping you would like to see? Also try putting your case statement under your HAVING statement.

Comment: Show us your `CREATE TABLE` statement and some of your test data.

Comment: Your second GROUP BY should work for the desired output you've shown. So it may be something else you are doing that is wrong. Can you update your question with the actual query (or queries) where you were using `group by e_id, CASE WHEN w_id in ('1','2') THEN w_id ELSE 0 END`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need to aggregate your value columns

```
create table table1(e_id int, w_id int, fee int)


insert into table1
values(1,1,100),(1,2,150),(1,3,50),(1,4,150),
(2,1,100),(2,1,150),(2,2,50),(2,4,150)


select
 e_id
,CASE WHEN w_id in ('1','2') THEN w_id ELSE 0 END as new_w_id
,SUM(CASE WHEN w_id = 1 THEN fee END) as value1
,SUM(CASE WHEN w_id = 2 THEN fee END) as value2
,SUM(CASE WHEN w_id not in ('1','2') THEN fee END) as value3
from table1
group by e_id
,CASE WHEN w_id in ('1','2') THEN w_id ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 3):

@BobKlimes answer is correct but you can also do it with a CTE and might find it easier to read/work with particularly with large/complex queries.  In my test they showed the same execution plan but YMMV.

```
WITH MyCTE AS (SELECT
                 e_id
                ,CASE WHEN w_id in ('1','2') THEN w_id ELSE 0 END as new_w_id
                ,CASE WHEN w_id = 1 THEN fee END as value1
                ,CASE WHEN w_id = 2 THEN fee END as value2
                ,CASE WHEN w_id not in ('1','2') THEN fee END as value3
            FROM table1
    ) 
SELECT e_id, new_w_id,
    SUM(value1) AS value1, SUM(value2) AS value2,
    SUM(value3) AS value3
FROM MyCTE
GROUP BY e_id, new_w_id
```

Comment: Upvoted, but chose the other answer as it's easier to apply in my case.